# How to return value in then()

Tags: angular, rest, typescript, ionic-framework, promise

I know similar questions have been asked. But I will explain the difference.

I have a function called `login()` that needs to return a User. This function calls another function which makes a call to my backend. The `login()` function needs to wait for a promise to finish before returning the User. The problem is, if I put the return in the `then()` it will say:

> [ts] A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must
>   return a value.

It needs to be returned because the function calling it will need the JWT of the User.

---

Simplified code:

```
login(user: User): User {
  this.user = user;
  //in between I fill some fields for the user
  this.loginPromise().then(user => {
    return user;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    //it doesn't make a difference wether I return a user here or not
}

loginPromise(): Promise<{}> {
 var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  this.restProvider.login(this.user)
  .subscribe(result => {
    const jwt = result.headers.get('JWT');
    const config = { ... result.body };
    if(config['result'] != 'failed'){
      this.user.$JsonWebToken = jwt;
      this.user.$passwordIsValid = true;
      this.user.$usernameIsValid = true;
      resolve(this.user);
    }
  }, err => {
    console.log("error: " + err);
    reject(err);
  });
 })
 return promise;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You `login` function can't return `User` object directly, it has to return `Promise<User>` object because it gets `user` object asynchronously.

```
login(user: User): Promise<User> {
  this.user = user;
  //in between I fill some fields for the user
  return this.loginPromise()
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

And then the consumer function will call `login` function and use `.then` to get the `user` value retrieved from the Server.

```
this.login().then(
  user => console.log(user);
)
```

Comment: this worked! Also, at the consumer I added another `.then(()=> { //do stuff });` so that code would only be fired after the previous bit finished.

Answer (score 1):

you can't return from `.then`, an option you can use here is to use `async await`, but in this case your `login` function will return `promise`, so you will need to call `.then` on login  when you will call `login` function

```
async login(user: User): Promise<User> {
  this.user = user;

  return await this.loginPromise();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change from this `loginPromise(): Promise<{}>` into something simple like this `loginPromise(){` I think it still returning a value